# PowerShell import-csv to database

Tags: powershell, csv

I want to insert csv data into access database via powershell. Im using below code to insert data. it executed successfully but the issue is that it insert blank rows in database. Im not sure where Im making mistake. Any Idea?

```
    $datafile='my_file.xls'
$dbfile='C:\CSVtoAccess\TestDatabase.accdb'
$connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=$dbfile"
$conn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection($connectionString)
$conn.Open()
$cmd = $Conn.CreateCommand()
Import-Csv $dataFile | 
     ForEach{
         $cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CSVDATA2(F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,F10,F11,F12,F13,F14,F15,F16,F17,F18,F19,F20,F21,F22,F23,F24,F25,F26) VALUES ('$($_.col1)', '$($_.col2)', '$($_.col3)', '$($_.col4)', '$($_.col5)', '$($_.col6)', '$($_.col7)', '$($_.col8)', '$($_.col9)', '$($_.col10)', '$($_.col11)', '$($_.col12)', '$($_.col13)', '$($_.col14)', '$($_.col15)', '$($_.col16)', '$($_.col17)', '$($_.col18)', '$($_.col19)', '$($_.col20)', '$($_.col21)', '$($_.col22)', '$($_.col23)', '$($_.col24)', '$($_.col25)', '$($_.col26)')"
         $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
     }
$conn.Close()
```

Any Idea where Im making mistake.

Regards,

Danish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by Powershell's handling of single `'` and double `"` quotes. As per the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847740.aspx),

> When you enclose a string in double quotation marks (a double-quoted
>   string), variable names that are preceded by a dollar sign ($) are
>   replaced with the variable's value before the string is passed to the
>   command for processing.
>
> When you enclose a string in single-quotation marks (a single-quoted
>   string), the string is passed to the command exactly as you type it. 
>   No substitution is performed.

Thus, this statement

```
"INSERT INTO CSVDATA2(F1,F2,F3...) VALUES ('$($_.col1)', '$($_.col2)', '$($_.col3)'...)"
```

will not expand any of the `$($_.coln)` into a values.

Use Powershells `-f` string formating, like so

```
$cmd.CommandText = "insert into foo(bar, zof) values ('{0}', '{1}')" -f $_.col1, $_.col2
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your reply. Now Im getting following error when I've rewrite sql.Error formatting a string: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the
argument list..

Comment: Error formatting a string: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the
argument list. Dont know where Im making mistake

Comment: Thanks. I've got what I was missing. But still its not getting values. There got an empty Values to sql. $_.col is not working. I dont know why.

Comment: This was helpful. I modified a little bit and solution work for me. here is the modification
$userobjects=Import-Csv $dataFile
ForEach ( $userobject in $userobjects ) 
{
#$sqlcmd="INSERT INTO TEST3(id,name,DOB,sex) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}')" -f $userobject.id, $userobject.name, $userobject.DOB, $userobject.SEX
$cmd.CommandText = $sqlcmd
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
}
$conn.Close()

Answer (score 0):

Is your input file an excel spreadsheet?  If so, you shouldn't be reading it with import-csv.  There are two workarounds:

1. In Excel, save the file as a csv file (with file extension .csv) instead of as a spreadsheet.
2. MS Access can load data directly from an XLS spreadsheet.  I know how to to this interactively in Access, but I don't know how to have powershell set up the command for Access to perform it.  Maybe another responder can fill in this piece.

Note, in addition, that the other response, about single quotes and double quotes is also part of the solution.

Comment: file is csv Ive deliberately put .xls extension.

Comment: It's a good idea to use the standard extensions in a standard way.  If it's a cvs file, it's best to give it the .csv extension.  However, that doesn't affect the problem you are now experiencing.